# My webapp runs fine locally but when using its deployed version it is giving axios error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, openai-api

[1]so i created a chatbot using openAi Api and when i run it on localhost it work totally good but as soon i use it in its deployed version it is giving me Axios error(404) also in console it is showing cannot post / error .cannot figure out what is the issue also i am using same backend url for other functions of the webapp there it is working fine.

front end code

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import LeftSidebar from "../src/components/LeftSidebar/LeftSidebar";
import CGLogo from './assets/chatGPT.png'
import AppLogo from './assets/app-logo.png'
import './Chatbot.css';

function Chatbot() {
 
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .post("https://stack-overflow-qfdp.onrender.com/chat", { prompt })
      .then((res) => {
        setResponse(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    
  };


  
  return (
    <div className="home-container-1">
      <LeftSidebar/>
      
      <div className="home-container-2">
    <div className="wrapper">
    <img src={AppLogo} alt="" className="app-logo" />   
    <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <img src={CGLogo} alt="" className={loading ? 'cg-logo loading' : 'cg-logo'} />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={prompt}
        onChange={(e) => setPrompt(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Ask anything... :)"
      />
      <button type="submit">Ask</button>
    </form>
    <p className="response-area">
    {loading ? 'loading...' : response}
      {/* Here will be my response  */}
    </p>
    <div className="footer">~ Copyrights ~ Prashant ~</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
  );
}

export default Chatbot ;
```

backend code

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import userRoutes from './routes/users.js'
import questionRoutes from './routes/Questions.js'
import answerRoutes from './routes/Answers.js'
import {config} from 'dotenv'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { Configuration , OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import postRoutes from "./routes/post.js";

dotenv.config({path : "./.env"})
dotenv.config();


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors({origin: "*",}));




app.get('/',(req, res) => {
     res.send("This is a stack overflow clone API")
 })


 app.use('/user' , userRoutes)
 app.use('/questions' , questionRoutes) 
 app.use('/answer' , answerRoutes)
 app.use("/post", postRoutes);


 const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.CHATBOT_KEY,
});


const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
app.post("/chat", async (req, res) => {
  const { prompt } = req.body;
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: "text-davinci-003", 
    prompt: prompt,
    max_tokens: 2048,
  });
  res.send(completion.data.choices[0].text);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const DATABASE_URL = process.env.CONNECTION_URL

mongoose
.connect( DATABASE_URL,{useNewUrlParser:true , useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => app.listen(PORT , () => {console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`)}))
.catch((err) => console.log(err.message))
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING
Object { stack: "On@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:333188\nhr</</d/<@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:347719\nd@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:347867\n", message: "Request failed with status code 404", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }
​
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
​
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​
message: "Request failed with status code 404"
​
name: "AxiosError"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
response: Object { data: '\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n

```
Cannot POST /chat
```

\n\n\n', status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", … }
​
stack: "On@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:333188\nhr</</d/<@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:347719\nd@https://stackovrflowclonebyprashant.netlify.app/static/js/main.5970f86a.js:2:347867\n"
​
: Object { constructor: On(e, t, n, r, a), toJSON: toJSON()
, stack: "", … }
​​
constructor: function On(e, t, n, r, a)
​​
isAxiosError: true
​​
stack: ""
​​
toJSON: function toJSON()
​​​
length: 0
​​​
name: "toJSON"
​​​
prototype: Object { … }
​​​
: function ()
​​
: Error.prototype { stack: "", … }

Comment: cannot say anything without seeing the error !

Comment: @NaveenRavi I just edited the post and added the error please help i am newbie in web developement

Comment: You should have got some config related values in the env file, I presume. As it's working locally, but not in the deployed version, ie, production build, it's possible that the .env file for prod is missing the necessary config parameters. Please check that too.